# SQL Server add specific word in all rows of specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The data in the table looks like

```
column 1       column 2
1338.          4
418.           3
ect.           4
```

I want to add 'sk' to all rows where column 2 = 4

Comment: You didn't ask something, or describe a problem. Have you tried anything yet? If you don't know how to update data, check the syntax of the `UPDATE` command

Comment: BTW what does *Excel* have to do with the question?

Comment: I import this from excel. Actually this was my first question and I had no time for tags

Comment: `'sk'` is a *string*.  Addition works on numbers and dates.  I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add 'sk' to all rows where column 2 = 4

Is this what you want?

```
update mytable
set column1 = concat(column1, 'sk')
where column2 = 4
```